# Bash commands tail fails to produce output in python

Tags: python, bash

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

I am working on using bash commands in python I found this example in Red hat magazine the tail command does not produce any output. I would like to understand why it is failing and I have also tried to import subprocess but that just hangs.

```
#Create Commands**strong text**
SPACE=`df -h`
MESSAGES=`tail /var/log/messages`

#Assign to an array(list in Python)
cmds=("$MESSAGES" "$SPACE")

#iteration loop
count=0
for cmd in "${cmds[@]}"; do
    count=$((count + 1))
    printf "Running Command Number %s \n" $count
    echo "$cmd"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Printing the command doesn't mean executing it. Look at Python's [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) library for API and examples for doing what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your reply I was able to get it working by importing subprocess and using subprocess.call = (["tail", "-f", "/var/log/messages"]) I still need to work on understanding how to get it to exit. I have seen posts referencing exit1, shell=true. That is the line to learn tonight. Thanks again.